# Exported Component from Adobe XD display either white or black screen in react-native app

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg

Ive designed some screens in Adobe XD. In adobe XD there is a plugin that exports the design as a React/ReactNative Component. Ive exported a design, just a background in this case, but when I run the app, the screen appears as a white or black screen, sometimes it will transition from white screen to black screen. the factors that affect this functionality are the export settings in adobe XD.

P.S.-I'm aware of other ways to implement a background, but im just trying to get react-native-svg working with a simple base case exporting from adobe XD because of how easy it is to design/prototype, I want it in my toolbox.

React Component export settings from Adobe XD plugin:
*create for react Native*-modify SVG nodes with uppercase/use specific template with react-native-svg imports
*remove dimensions*-remove width & height from root SVG tag
*forward ref*-setting to true will forward ref to the root SVG tag

I've tried all amalgamations and nothing displays the design.

current react-native version: 0.59.5
current react-native-svg version: 9.5.1

the exported adobe (abridged) design as a react component:

```
import React from "react";
import Svg, {
  Defs,
  LinearGradient,
  Stop,
  ClipPath,
  Rect,
  G,
  Circle,
  Line
} from "react-native-svg";

const BackgroundComponent = () => (
   <Svg width={375} height={812} viewBox="0 0 375 812">
    <Defs>
      <LinearGradient
        id="a"
        x1={0.5}
        x2={0.5}
        y2={1}
        gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
      >
        <Stop offset={0} stopColor="#fff" />
        <Stop offset={1} stopColor="#ffb051" />
      </LinearGradient>
      <ClipPath id="c">
        <Rect className="a" width={375} height={812} />
      </ClipPath>
      <ClipPath id="e">
        <Rect width={375} height={812} />
      </ClipPath>
    </Defs>
  </Svg>
);

export default BackgroundComponent;
```

I expect the screen to appear similar to the design created in Adobe XD, but its a white/black screen.

Comment: i have the same problem... do you find a solution?

Comment: No. Bounty the question